# SocketConnect Options

Tags: socket

I have a SocketConnection which fails every so often and I can't seem to find a way to reduce the default timeout. I did try TimeConstrained but that seems not to work consistently for network connections.

Comment: Welcome to MMA.SE! You will need to provide quite a few more details for anyone to be able to help you out. I am not sure how you are using `TimeConstrained` here.

Comment: This is the minimum example `TimeConstrained [ FailureQ[s = SocketConnect["192.168.1.67:22"]], 5]`